# Firebase Database Search Query not working properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a social app such as facebook but I got stuck when doing the find friends activity using Firebase Database Query.

**The problem is that the search results (users) are not displaying.**
**When I put allUsersRef as a parameter in setQuery() the users are displayed, but when I put searchFriendsQuery as the parameter it does not displaying anything.**
I have look many answers to solve my problem but none of them work.

This is the method in which I got stuck, as I said this method searches through the firebase database by fullname and then it displays the users that match the user input:

```
private fun searchFriends(userInputText: String) {
        Log.i("SEARCH",userInputText)
        Toast.makeText(this,"Searching...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val searchFriendsQuery = allUsersRef.orderByChild("fullname")
            .startAt(userInputText)
            .endAt(userInputText + "\uf8ff")

        val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FindFriends> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindFriends>()
            .setQuery(searchFriendsQuery,FindFriends::class.java)
            .build()

        val firebaseRecyclerAdapter = object: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends,FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: FindFriendsViewHolder, position: Int, model: FindFriends) {
                viewHolder.setProfilesInfo(model)
            }
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FindFriendsViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, parent, false)
                return FindFriendsViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()
        searchOutputList.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
    }
```

This is my viewHolder class:

```
class FindFriendsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mView = itemView

        private val friendsProfileImage: CircleImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.find_users_profile_image)
        private val friendsFullName: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.find_user_full_name)
        private val friendsStatus: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.find_user_status)

        fun setProfilesInfo(friends: FindFriends){
            friendsFullName.text = friends.fullname
            friendsStatus.text = friends.status
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .load(friends.profileimage)
                .into(friendsProfileImage)
        }
    }
```

This is my module class:

```
class FindFriends {
    var profileimage: String? = null
    var fullname: String? = null
    var status: String? = null
}
```

These are the values of the variables in the code:

```
private lateinit var allUsersRef: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var searchOutputList: RecyclerView
private lateinit var searchInputText: EditText

allUsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

searchOutputList = findViewById(R.id.search_list)
searchOutputList.setHasFixedSize(true)
searchOutputList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

searchInputText = findViewById(R.id.search_input_box).toString()
```

JSON exported file:

```
"Users" : {
    "Q4RWEkf8YsRnQppwpEYrSMKa0M82" : {
      "country" : "Mexico",
      "dateofbirth" : "Unknown",
      "fullname" : "Oswaldo Escobedo",
      "gender" : "Unknown",
      "profileimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhero-8778b.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Images%2FQ4RWEkf8YsRnQppwpEYrSMKa0M82.jpg?alt=media&token=44fe278b-a7f0-42c7-90b9-dfbcc57bf733",
      "relationshipstatus" : "Unknown",
      "status" : "Active",
      "username" : "oswi73"
    },
    "h7DPxSQax3PNYFcXNDSgk4H9zyF2" : {
      "country" : "Mexico",
      "dateofbirth" : "Unknown",
      "fullname" : "Jenny Balandran",
      "gender" : "Unknown",
      "profileimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhero-8778b.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Images%2Fh7DPxSQax3PNYFcXNDSgk4H9zyF2.jpg?alt=media&token=99633998-46f4-4a64-806d-3a8bc7ec0580",
      "relationshipstatus" : "Unknown",
      "status" : "Active",
      "username" : "oescob16"
    },
    "nq6OPYGHuAdCApuyXhLYHLLdOtA3" : {
      "country" : "México ",
      "dateofbirth" : "Unknown",
      "fullname" : "Oswaldo Escobedo",
      "gender" : "Unknown",
      "profileimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myhero-8778b.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Images%2Fnq6OPYGHuAdCApuyXhLYHLLdOtA3.jpg?alt=media&token=55f8c342-9e74-400f-8038-5a7af208510e",
      "relationshipstatus" : "Unknown",
      "status" : "Active",
      "username" : "oescobedo3 "
    }
  }
```

This is the log value of userInputText:

```
2020-06-14 19:26:11.288 10129-10129/com.example.bemyhero I/SEARCH: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{e57e7ff VFED..CL. .F...... 30,103-1080,313 #7f08012a app:id/search_input_box aid=1073741824}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to: 1) log the value of `userInputText` and then include the updated code and its output, 2) the JSON at `allUsersRef` in your database (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already added the JSON file. But I don't know hot to log the value of userInputText. Could you help me?

Comment: Just do something like `Log.i("SEARCH", userInputText)` at the top of `searchFriends`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I already added the Log, now what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have called `toString` on an an `EditText` field. Passing that to the database won't work, as you'll be searching the database for the literal string `"androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{e57e7ff VFED..CL. .F...... 30,103-1080,313 #7f08012a app:id/search_input_box aid=1073741824}"`.

You'll want to get the text from the field, and search for that:

```
searchFriends(textField.getText().toString());
```